# How to edit wicked time picker input field

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker, wickedpicker

I am using wicked picker for time and date picker. For time picker input field i 
 cannot edit the time. I can delete time but cannot type. How to manually type the time?

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control timepicker" type="text" placeholder="End Time" id="timepicker-two" />
</div>
```

JS code

```
$('.timepicker').wickedpicker();
```

This is the link i have downloaded

https://github.com/ericjgagnon/wickedpicker

Comment: Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this one out too. I've tried the options for clearable, but no luck.

```
Var options = {
    twentyFour = true,
    clearable = true
};
$('.timepicker').wickedpicker(options);
```

The clearable is the only option I could find that would come close to this. But all it seems to do is allow the user to delete the field. It does not allow for a manual entry though.